# Integrating Clean code when mixing PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, oop

I'm finding an organisation a major problem with mixing PHP and HTML, it just looks horrible, so i'm wondering if it's a viable option to create a set of object oriented methods such as this:

```
class MainOO {

    public $Database;

    public function __construct($Server,$User, $Password, $DB){
        if ($this->Database = new mysqli($Server,$User,$Password,$DB)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function User_Login(){

        $Get_Usr_Info = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT ID, Password, Salt FROM Users WHERE Username=?");
        $Get_Usr_Info->bind_param('s',$_POST['username']);
        $Get_Usr_Info->execute();
        $Get_Usr_Info->store_result();
        $User_Number = $Get_Usr_Info->num_rows;
        $Get_Usr_Info->bind_result($UserID, $Stored_Password, $Stored_Salt);
        $Get_Usr_Info->fetch();
        $Get_Usr_Info->close();
        if ($User_Number !== 1){
            $Error = "Wrong Username Specified Or Password Is Incorrect";
            header ("Location: index.php?Errors=".urlencode($Error));
            exit;
        }
        // Continue with login script 

    }
    public function Logout(){
        if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_DISABLED){
            session_destroy();
            header ("Location: LoggedOut.php");
            exit;
        }
    }


}
```

Then HTML side:

```
<?php 
  include "MainOO.php"; 
  $MainOO = new MainOO("host","user","password","database");
?>
<div class="example">
  <div class="example left">
  <?php
   $MainOO->User_Login();
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's still mixing PHP & HTML, but it's making look a hell of a lot neater than having heaps of PHP in the middle of HTML.

I'm fully aware I could migrate over to a MVC Framework (which this topic is looking like) already setup, or even use a template engine such as smarty, but I want to avoid this as much as possible.. So is this a viable option to have neater PHP code within html?

Comment: It works, right? It looks better, according to you, right? You are aware of even better alternatives... I'm not sure what there is to add.

Comment: I suggest to have a look into the Zend Code Style Guide http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use an isset() in the code too 
e.g

`<?= (isset($variable)) ? $variable : ''; ?>`

e.g if variable isset then display it otherwise display nothing

Comment: Nothing but errors :P

Comment: I didn't read through the whole question, but, using short_open_tags is deprecated because they are off by default. You want to avoid undefined variable notices and warnings, that's ok, but the suggested way ain't the best practice